# Omission of variable in regression model

Tags: statistical-significance, multiple-regression, descriptive-statistics, restrictions

[image]

I am currently solving a question about the omission of variables in a regression model.

The question says that $R^2$ decreases after two variables are omitted in the model; I understand this part. However I don't understand why the restricted model will not have the lower $SSE$ of 27108. 
$R^2= ESS/TSS$. Here, I assume TSS stays constant... 
When $R^2$ decreases then surely $ESS$ will now be a smaller value. Why is it that $SSE$ of the restricted model will be bigger than $SSE$ of the unrestricted model ?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not missreading? SSE (sum of squared errors) is not ESS (explained sum of squares). When ESS decreases, SSE has to increase...

Comment: You need to add the self study tag.

Comment: The economist might also mix these up: SSE can mean "sum squared estimate" or "sum squared error." SSR can mean "sum squared residual" or "sum squared regression." Notice how SSR and SSE swap meanings?!  Your use of SSE *does* specify one of those meanings, though. Can you tell which one?